# Will scheduled Job/Trigger in RAMJobStore lost if we set offline.html

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

Currently, I plan to run schedule to send email every week.
What I hope is the trigger will stop when the apps is offline. Then reschedule again when AppStart. 
After read the documentation, still can't find out. 
I tried in local machine, it seem like RAMJobStore continue running, even apps is offline. How can I stop it when bring the Apps offline ?

Please share me some idea or information. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tried, I found out the trigger will off when App_offline.htm in the apps folder.

I setup below code, then click on Start button to trigger the schedule.
Suppose will receive total 5 Emails every 30 second. If the Testing Email failed to send, suppose will receive an Error Email.

After received 2nd Email, I copy paste App_offline.html into folder. At the end, I never receive anything. Of course, after I remove App_offline.htm nothing happen too. Thanks !

p/s: the code just like that, no extra Web.Config applied so far.

```
public ActionResult Start()
{
    IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
    scheduler.Start();

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Jobclass>().Build();
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(30)
        .WithRepeatCount(4))
        .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public class Jobclass:IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        string sMailStatus = MyClass.mailTemplate("myEmail@gmail.com", "myEmail@gmail.com", 
                     "Testing Email - " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), "Testing");
            if (sMailStatus != "sent")
            {
                MyClass.mailTemplate("myEmail@gmail.com", "myEmail@gmail.com", 
                    "Error : Testing Email", sMailStatus);
            }
     }
}
```